# luaotfload always being invoked

Tags: luatex

Every time I run lualatex, luaotfload-tool is being invoked. As a trivial example,

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage{luatexja} % ltjclasses, ltjsclasses を使うときはこの行不要
\begin{document}
\section{はじめてのLua\TeX-ja}
ちゃんと日本語が出るかな？
\subsection{出たかな？}
長い文章を入力するとちゃんと右端のところで折り返されるかな？
大丈夫そうな気がするけど．ちょっと不安だけど何事も挑戦だよね．
\end{document}
```

This file is 'junk.lua':

```
$ make junk.pdf
lualatex < junk.lua && mv texput.pdf junk.pdf
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
**LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5

L3 programming layer <2020-08-07>
*(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltjsarticle.cls
Document Class: ltjsarticle 2020/05/30 ltjsclasses 
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.sty
    . . .
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjfont.sty
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty)
ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros)
(/opt/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjdefs.sty
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
```

'luaotfload-tool' with diagnostic output shows all the 'fontloader-*.lua'
files have checksum errors, but I have no idea if this is relevant. I read
in another post that luaotfload can do this if the font name is wrong, but
this is vanilla luatex (well, luatexja) so I can't see why that would be a
problem.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

P.S.

Running 'luaotfload-tool -v -vvv -u' (command copied from elsewhere) I get a massive amount of output, but output at the end may be significant:

```
luaotfload | db : Found 4377 font files; 0 new, 0 stale entries.
luaotfload | db : Creating filename map.
luaotfload | db : Conflicting basename: "ASANA" already indexed in category texmf, ignoring.
luaotfload | db : Conflicting barename: "ASANA" already indexed in category texmf/ttc, ignoring.
luaotfload | db : Analyzing families.
luaotfload | db : Analyzing shapes, weights, and styles.
luaotfload | db : Ordering design sizes.
luaotfload | db : Collecting fontnames.
luaotfload | db : Rebuilt in 29611 ms.
luaotfload | db : No new or removed fonts, skip saving to disk.
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache saved.
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache emptied.
luaotfload | db : Fonts in the database: 2162
```

'Not saving to disk'? 'Lookup cache' 'saved' then 'emptied'?

P.P.S I am starting to get a bad feeling about lua; it appears to be rather shoddy:

```
$ luaotfload-tool --find "Libertinus Serif"
...texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-features.lua:432: attempt to index a nil value (field 'normal')
```

I ran this on Solaris and Linux with the same result.

UPDATE:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS euros 5.11 11.4.0.15.0 i86pc i386 i86pc
$ luaotfload-tool -D -u    
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
$ luaotfload-tool -u
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
$ luaotfload-tool -D -u 
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
```

whereas,

```
Linux zephyr 4.1.12-124.30.1.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Thu Aug 8 01:38:50 GMT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ luaotfload-tool -D -u     
$ luaotfload-tool -u
$
```

That is, on my linux machine the 'database' files are built so running with '-u' does nothing except scan files presumably. In contrast, on Solaris it always complains about 'Font names database' not being found which suggests some file(s) is or are not being written, or are perhaps written but null.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use another extension and then to just pass the filename to lualtex instead of piping the file in, but that's not the cause of your issue. For some reason you don't have a font name database. What does you logfile (texput.log) say?

Comment: Do you run lualatex in some kind of container?

Comment: This is the first time I've used lualatex; I expected it to be like 'tex' etc. and read the file name from the command line. This gave rise to a very obscure error; I finally tried redirecting from stdin and it runs, at least. No, I am not using a container.

Comment: If I knew where the database file was, I could check to see why it's not being written which appears to be the case. The texput.log file shows nothing untoward, except that in the Root cache directory, $TEXMFVAR/luatex-cache/generic/names, luaotfload-names.luc is zero length; don't know if this is significant.

Comment: I wouldn't call ltjsarticle and luatexja "trivial". Start with a document using article.cls and a few english words.

Comment: @N.Hunt The "attempt to index a nil value (field 'normal')" is a known bug in the latest release and already fixed in the development branch (so it will be fixed after the next release) (https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/168)

Comment: Ah, many thanks for that information; I should point out that my original problem, stated in the form of running lualatex, is perhaps misleading. The error I see from runnnig lualatex I can reproduce by simply running 'luaotfload--tool -u'. It always goes through the same process of reading files etc. etc. I would expect that if indices or whatever are up-to-date then the command should just exit.

Comment: @N.Hunt That's the idea, but without a full log it's hard to say why it's rebuilding every time.

Comment: Of course, if you explicitly request an update with `-u` it will at least scan over the fonts to ensure that it's up to date. That is consistent with the log output you provided for luaotfload-tool.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered what is causing this problem; the luaotfload-names.luc file is zero length. I installed the latest texlive on another machine (linux) and everything works fine. The solaris version is broken, but I don't know how to fix it apart from perhaps recompiling the lua interpreter with the Sun compiler and see how that goes.